# How do spring boot aspect catch exception of para parser exception in Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

Im new in Spring, and trying use the AOP aspect to handle all the possible exceptions in my program. It works well except for the Request para parser exception, for my aspect can not catch it. The case is as follow:
 This is my Aspect code

```
@Aspect
@Order(5)
@Component
public class WebLogAspect {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebLogAspect.class);
  @Pointcut("execution(public * com.test.api..*.*(..))")
  public void webLog() {}

  @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "webLog()", throwing = "e")
  public void afterThrowing(Throwable e) {

      LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
   }
}
```

Then comes the Controller part, its package path is exactly included in the Aspect Pointcut.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

   @RequestMapping("/test")
   public Long testApi(
     @RequestParam(value = "para", required = true)Long testPara) {
        /*           
        do some thing;
        */ 
       return testPara;
     }
}
```

The thing is, if I send a request like "127.0.0.1:9999/test?para=ABC", The testApi will throw a MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException, but it will not be caught by my Aspect.  However, any other exception raised in "do some thing" CAN be caught.

So, Im confused, whether my configuration on Aspect is wrong, or the Aspect just can not catch such exceptions.

Really appreciate your advice!

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Following @M.Deinum's comment, I add a GlobalExceptionHandler with the Annotation "@RestControllerAdvice". Now, such exceptions which are not thrown inside the controller can be handled.

Appending the full stack exception

```
ERROR com.test.exception.GlobalExceptionHandler:32 - Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABC"
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.*MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException*: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABC"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1712)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1699)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABC"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.valueOf(Long.java:803)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:468)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:713)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:120)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: Are you sure MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException is thrown within testApi method? I guess it is thrown from other place and then just propagated into testApi itself

Comment: It cannot catch your exception. The exception is thrown before the actual method is getting invoked. Hence before the aspect is executed.

Comment: @fg78cn Yes, I also guess the exception is thrown before the testApi is processed.   But not sure for that, and come here ask for advice : )

Comment: @M.Deinum  Thanks! Thats what Im guessing.

Comment: @EricOlivier - You can catch Throwable in your testApi and then re-throw it, this way aspect will work out.

Comment: Use an `@ExceptionHandler` on a `@ControllerAdvice` for these kind of situations.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace instead of online the name of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extending the `OncePerRequestFilter` class and overriding the `doFilterInternal` method. Something like following will do the trick:

```
    public void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) { 
    // Any exception thrown from your code can be handled or retrhown from here.
    }
}
```